# R - Writing a generic function that will colour different lines in a ggplot line graph based on the parameters

Tags: r, ggplot2

I found the title difficult to word but essentially I want to be able to colour different lines of the plot based on parameters passed to a function call. I can't provide my data but the following code will generate a data frame in the same shape and style as mine. It will also generate the base plot for what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
a = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5)
b = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
c = sample(1:100, 25, replace = TRUE)
df = data.frame(a,b,c)
ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = c, group = b, colour = b))+
    geom_line(linetype = "dashed", size = 1, colour = "grey")
```

Essentially I'd like to be able to pass to the function a vector containing say the values "a", "b", "e" and then the plot will change. The "a", "b", and "e" lines will now be in colour and there will be a legend on the side with the name and colour of the line.

I've tried a few methods, the closest to being successful was adding the lines in a for loop, but I couldn't get the legend to work and all the lines came in the same colour.

I realize this question is probably a duplicate but I've been searching to no avail for a couple days so even being pointed to an answered question may be helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the `colour` argument in `geom_line`:

```
a = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5)
b = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
c = sample(1:100, 25, replace = TRUE)
df = data.frame(a,b,c)
ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = c, group = b, colour = b))+
  geom_line(linetype = "dashed", size = 1)
```

Otherwise you are overriding your color mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Your plot function could look like this (pass the values of `b` that you want plotted in the `filter_values` argument):

```
custom_plot <- function(.data, filter_values = c("a", "b", "e")) {
  ggplot(.data[which(.data$b %in% filter_values), ],
    aes(x = a, y = c, colour = b)) + 
    geom_line(linetype = "dashed", size = 1)
}

custom_plot(df)
```

[image]

Please note that this is a very specific function which makes silent assumptions about the input data.frame (namely, that it has has columns a, b, and c) and does not check if the assumptions are fulfilled - a proper function should do that.